# mongodb data directory permissions

Tags: mongodb

Earlier i was storing all the mongodb data files in /var/lib/mongodb directory..and the dbpath entry in /etc/mongodb.conf was /var/lib/mongodb..

Now i want to change the data directory to /vol/db..so I created the directory /vol/db and changed the permissions using sudo chown -R `id -u` /vol/db and changed the db path entry to /vol/db in /etc/mongodb.conf

now when i start the mongodb using sudo service mongodb start..i am getting this error in /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

http://pastebin.com/C0tv8HQN

i need help..where I am wrong?

Comment: i am using sudo chown -R id -u /vol/db and sudo chown -R username:username /vol/db

Comment: Can you paste the output of ls -altrh /vol and ls -altrh /vol/db?

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you reply back if you have solved this?

Answer (score 55):

I was having the same problem, but was able to solve it thanks to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongodb-mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder?answertab=votes#tab-top). You need to make sure that `/vol/db/` is owned by `mongodb`.

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /vol/db/
```

If you get the error `chown: invalid user: 'mongodb:mongodb'`, check `/etc/passwd` to see if there is a similar user that exists (ex. `mongod`).

Comment: what if I get an invalid user error and there isn't anything in /etc/passwd that is similar

Comment: in case my service name is `mongod`, what will be my user:group?

Comment: probably mongod, try: groups mongod

Answer (score 19):

The easiest would be

```
sudo chmod 777 /data/db
```

Comment: this worked for me.. when I ran sudo chown mongodb:mongoDB /vol/db i received : "illegal group name"... this solution worked

Comment: This command will give very open permissions to the directory in question. The answer from @Kaezarrex (`sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db`) should have the desired effect without opening the permissions so widely.

Comment: Never give 777 to a file, specially if it's on a production server

Comment: yeah this "works" if you don't care about security whatsoever.

Comment: Leaving world-writable directories on a server is a bad idea... Any user can delete / edit any file in that directory

Answer (score 7):

If after changing permissions and ownership of the new db path, you're still seeing this issue, run `getenforce` to see if you are using a system with SELinux running in enforce mode.
If getenforce returns 'enforcing', it's likely selinux is the cause of the permissions error, since mongodb is now running outside it's original context scope since the db location changed out of /var/lib/...

I don't know the details, but a brute force way then to resolve the issue without writing your own selinux policy for the new context is to simply turn off selinux :-/

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Ideally, you'd figure out how to update the selinux policy if you're planning to run in production.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to check what is the error by reading mongo log

```
tail -50 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

you can immediately find the problem(including permission ones)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /vol/db && sudo chown $USER /vol/db
```

Comment: Add -R to this and then it worked for me, to recurse all sub files and folders: ```sudo -R chmod 755 /data/db && sudo chown -R $USER /data/db```