# Mongo /data/db should be writable?

Tags: mongodb, macos, chmod

I'm starting with MongoDB and it looks like it needs a writable /data/db.
So I created a folder /data/db as superuser but then when I start it requires the rights the write on that directory (makes sense).

My question is : should I do a chmod 777 on /data/db ? Or should I run mongod as sudo ?

According to : [mongodb Mongod complains that there is no /data/db folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongodb-mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder?rq=1)

I should do

```
grep mongo /etc/passwd
```

but that does not return anything

And `sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data/db` gives me a `chown: mongod: illegal group name`

Thanks

EDIT:
I've `chown -R totosh:staff /data/db` (totosh being my username) and now it works. Is it the right thing to do though ?