# Mongodb not connecting to localhost?

Tags: mongodb

im trying to connect with mongodb but its not showing `waiting for connection on port 27017`. I need the localhost!

[image]

Comment: It says right there: `data directory /data/db not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongod complains that there is no /data/db folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder)

Comment: its working now omg, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing this `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` and then `mongod` then this `sudo chmod -R go+w /data/db`