# Mongo DB configuration file is not at default location changed it to /root/mongod.conf. then systemctl commad not able to consume this file

Tags: mongodb, file, configuration

So when ,trying to start monogdb service by command `systemctl start mongod`,
it is giving error as Permission denied to read conf file.

Given same permission as default location conf file to custome location conf file and also update the file /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service and changed the

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
```

to

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /root/mongod.conf"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: try sudo in front of it  `sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: tried no luck with sudo also @ViharManchala

Comment: What were the permissions of file /etc/mongod.conf. Can you do `ll /etc/mongod.conf` and show me what it is?

Comment: [root@ip-172-31-32-91 ec2-user]# ll /etc/mongod.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 mongod mongod 801 Mar 13 07:19 /etc/mongod.conf
[root@ip-172-31-32-91 ec2-user]# ll /root/mongod.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 mongod mongod 801 Mar 12 09:51 /root/mongod.conf

Comment: Can you modify the permissions and give it an execute permissions. It just has read access, you may have to add execute permissions. Lemme know if it works

Comment: Also, you can try by changing the owner of the file to root, and then use the command that I have given you before `sudo systemctl start mongod`

Comment: ll /root/mongod.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 801 Mar 12 09:51 /root/mongod.conf

Comment: sudo systemctl start mongod
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-03-15 06:25:11 UTC; 21s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 4693 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=2).
Mar 15 06:25:11 ip-172-31-32-91.us-west-2.compute.internal mongod[4693]: Error reading config file: Permission denied

Comment: seems to be issue is with systemd when i try to run /usr/bin/mongod -f /root/mongod.conf service started successfully, but systemctl should work as it is standard way of doing it , am i missing something from systemd point of view ?

Comment: Need help on this

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? I found answers on link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder?rq=1`

Comment: not found any answers on above link @ViharManchala

Comment: @ViharManchala it is easily reproducible ,i have give all the possible tries [root@ip-172-31-34-163 ec2-user]# ls -lrt /root/mongod.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mongod mongod 806 Apr 17 06:07 /root/mongod.conf
this permission given ti config file