# Read-only file system when attempting mkdir /data/db on Mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

I am trying to create a new folder in the root directory.

I tried all kinds of examples.

```bash
sudo mkdir /data/db
```

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

I keep getting:

```
mkdir: /data: Read-only file system
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283257/mongodb-doesnt-work-on-latest-mac-os10-15 This answers the comments below.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283257/mongodb-doesnt-work-on-latest-mac-os10-15

Comment: [Techno Peace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12741466) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233947) saying "Due to Catalina OS update, it changed. Follow this link to achieve: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/"

Comment: This is still an issue on Big Sur

Answer (score 230, accepted):

If you have a Mac and updated to Catalina or more recent version, then the root folder is no
longer writable.

I just changed the directory somewhere else.

Been using this command for now

```
mongod --dbpath=/Users/user/data/db
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it permanent? I have to type it every time I start the MongoDB server!

Comment: @AVPaul Maybe not the best solution, but you could make an alias that refers to your path.

Comment: Im actually getting Data directory /Users/user/data/db not found., terminating. Even though I created the folder

Comment: @JeffGoes I am assuming you did not replace the user with the actual name.

Comment: Despite this working (and solving my problem), it seems hacky

Comment: @AlexL It's working for me too. But do I have to type mongod --dbpath=/Users/my_USER_name/data/db everytime I want to run my dev mongo db? Because next time when I run mongod, it is saying /data/db not found

Comment: you can make it permanent by setting the dbPath in mongoDB config file
if you're using mac it's under /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.
then add the following :
"storage:
  dbPath: path to your db directory"

Comment: I forgot how annoying updating OS X is no wonder I always resist it

Comment: It might be worth noting that `/usr` is a hidden folder. To 'see' it, press cmd + shift + . (dot). That being sad, I don't seem to have a folder `etc` in `/usr/local/`. Now what?

Comment: This answer is a work around but does not seem to be what the question is asking.

Comment: why can't the Community Version of Mongo (and Brew) be updated to fix this? anyone know how I can submit a PR lol

Answer (score 107):

from the official docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

install [homebrew](https://brew.sh) and run the following commands

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

then

`brew tap mongodb/brew`

then

`brew install mongodb-community@4.2`

and

`brew services start mongodb-community`

or

`mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

then

`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod`

and

`mongo`

to verify you can run `show dbs` in the mongo shell

Comment: brew services start mongodb-community => Error: Formula `mongodb-community` is not installed.

You have to launched:
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.2

Comment: I wish I could click upvote button more than once.

Answer (score 59):

With the new macOS Catalina update, the folder `/data/db` becomes read-only, you cannot modify it. Follow this procedure to create a DB in another folder:

1. Change `mongod` directory :

   `sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db`
2. Give it an alias to use it as `mongod`:

   `alias mongod="sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db"`
3. Just type `mongod` in your terminal, it should work.

**Extra** => If you need to give it current user rights, use this line of code :

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

(Just for info -> `$(whoami)` is just a variable that returns your current user)

Comment: I did this before step 1: `sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db` && ```sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db```. Not sure if these folders exist already but combined @xgqfrms's answer with this one. Thanks so much for this, was driving me crazy.

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: even if I change ownership of `/System/Volumes/Data/data/db` I still need to provide password everytime I run the `mongod` command

Comment: I've tried several solution, the only one that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: i struggled for 2 days.now its working for me ..appreciate

Comment: it is working in mac m1 chip

Answer (score 17):

### You can't create a folder on the root directory on Mac Catalina anymore!

https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/features/

### Dedicated system volume

> macOS Catalina runs in a dedicated, read-only system volume — which means it is completely separate from all other data and helps improve the reliability of macOS.

```sh
# macOS Catalina, mkdir path
$ sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

# give permissions
$ sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

```sh
# macOS 10.14.x -
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db

# macOS 10.15.x +
$ sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

### refs

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250720711

https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX15WbKidXY

Answer (score 12):

To make a permanent change of the path of mongod `db` folder.

Following [these docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition) they say roughly this. If mongod is started with brew services:

```
$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

It will use config file at path `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

---

To fix this, edit the config file:

```
$ vim /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

And change the `dbPath` e.g. to your home directory like this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /Users/<username>/data/db
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Save the file and restart mongod with brew:

```
$ brew services restart mongodb-community@4.2
```

Comment: this did not work for me, mongo is still looking in /data/db

Comment: @Xen_mar were you trying to run mongod after editing the file? Apparently mongod is already run by brew services start

Answer (score 8):

I am at a loss why Apple did that.. So now, we can not have any root level directory other than theirs ? This just doesn't make any sense and people creating with root privileges those folders know what they are doing

Comment: typical apple: helicopter-parenting their users

Answer (score 7):

If you are on mac and facing the issue then below command is useful, 
`whoami` variable will get the current user

```
mongod --dbpath=/Users/$(whoami)/data/db
```

Answer (score 7):

So, with macOS Catalina Apple created a new Volume for security purposes. If you’re on macOS Catalina, you'll need to create the `/data/db` folder in `System/Volumes/Data`.

Follow these commands

1. `sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db`
2. `sudo chown -R` id -un `/System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

Start MongoDB

3. `brew services run mongodb-community`
4. Enjoy

Comment: `brew services run mongodb-community` gave me `Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb-community".`

Answer (score 5):

I did this:

```
mkdir -p usr/local/var/mongodb/data/db
```

since the new path that is "usr/local/var/mongodb".

Answer (score 5):

Default Paths for the mongodb-community Formula

In addition to installing the MongoDB server and tool binaries, the mongodb-community formula creates:

- a configuration file: /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
- a log directory path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
- a data directory path: /usr/local/var/mongodb

then it worked for me:

```
mkdir -p usr/local/var/mongodb/data/db
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me as I was undergoing a Udemy course:
1. Install HomeBrew by typing this into your terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Move your old /data/db folder (if you want to backup your current dbs) into a non root folder and proceed with the next step
3. Run in Terminal
   a) `brew uninstall mongodb`
   b) If needed run `brew uninstall --force mongodb`
   c) `brew tap mongodb/brew`
   d) `brew install mongodb-community`
   e) `brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community`
4. All you need now is to run mongo in the Terminal and you'll see the mongo shell symbol >.

Please let me know if this works ;) 
It took me almost 2 hours to figure it out, based on this article:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362883/mongodb-doesnt-work-after-update-to-macos-catalina-10-15

Cheers,
Radu

Answer (score 4):

To add on to what [David Buck wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423909), first you have to actually make the directory.  You can do that with:

> sudo mkdir /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

If you're getting this error:

> "Error parsing command line: unrecognised option
> '--dbpath/System/Volumes/Data/data/db' try 'mongod --help' for more
> information"

after creating the alias, it's just because David Buck (while making a really helpful comment) missed a space in his answer.

To fix this, type

> unalias mongod

and then type

> alias mongod="sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db"

Comment: It wasn't me... credit should go to Eugène Beliaev. I just edited their answer for formatting...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `/data/` directory. That is reserved for the APFS filesystem. Check [Bombich’s](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/working-apfs-volume-groups) blog about this issue.

Comment: So, could this read-only file issue be solved? I have the same problem

Comment: No, you need to use another name for your directory. A possible solution could be to create the data directory inside another directory which is allowed as a root directory.

Answer (score 1):

With macOS Catalina, you can no longer store files or data in the read-only system volume, nor can you write to the "root" directory ( / ) from the command line, such as with Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I create a gist with simple steps to install and run mongodb on catalina

```
# install homebrew (https://brew.sh/) and run the following commands
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@4.2

## --- aliases to set in your zshrc file

# open your zshrc file
open ~/.zshrc
# copy and paste shorcuts in the end of the file
alias mongod='brew services run mongodb-community'
alias mongod-start='brew services start mongodb-community' #will start MongoDB automatically when you login into your Macbook
alias mongod-status='brew services list'
alias mongod-stop='brew services stop mongodb-community'

# restart your terminal
# type mongod in your terminal for run service & mongod-stop for finish it
# test your mongodb connection with
mongo
show dbs
```

https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/cf19baa91b1d79d8ae2b305fb7e1f799

Answer (score 0):

Mac version Catalina made the root folder is no longer writable.

Brew has an updated version of mongodb to use a new path (which it creates itself), `/usr/local/var/mongodb` and following these instructions will fix the issue:

[Guide to installing updated mongodb-community-edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition)

`brew install mongodb-community@VERSION` where the first VERSION with the fix is 4.2