# should I be worried if MongoDB server version: 4.2.9 and MongoDB shell version v4.4.1 do not match?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a Mongodb server in my app.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB",{
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

When I run `mongo` in the terminal for some reason `mongod` does not work.  This is the output I get.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("a0a211a2-c838-4a04-830e-8cbb4567bed5") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.9
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
Mongo-Hacker 0.0.14
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-11-02T18:06:15.664+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-11-02T18:06:15.664+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled 
for the database.
2020-11-02T18:06:15.664+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data 
and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-11-02T18:06:15.664+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
uncaught exception: don't know how to show [freeMonitoring]
uncaught exception: don't know how to show [automationNotices]
uncaught exception: don't know how to show [nonGenuineMongoDBCheck]
Brian-Pattersons-iMac(mongod-4.2.9) test>
```

I am not sure if I should be worried or will this work nonetheless.  I have looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034955/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-data-db-on-mac)
but it is not clear as to what i should do.  I have currently installed MongoDB on my Mac which is running Catalina 10.15.7 using the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) . Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: try updating mongo-hacker to the latest version it should fix.

Comment: or may be try removing mongo-hacker as it is not mandatory.