# installing MongoDB to Mac

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need help to solve an error that happened while installing MongoDB into Macbook.
I run this command to kick off installing.

```
brew install mongosh
```

ALthough I got a warning msg, it seemed like fine.
[image]

I waited so long, and the installation got finally done.
Here is the screenshot of the end.

[image]

As you can see, I typed below to check if it was successfully installed.

```
mongosh --version
1.2.2
```

Finally I tried to run MongoDB, so typed "mongosh". And I got an error to run it and connect to db called cluster0.

```
mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 621d2adedeee61396fddb367
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.2.2
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
takeichimasahironoMacBook-Air:~ masa$ mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.8tjjn.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --apiVersion 1 --username mongo
Enter password: *****
Current Mongosh Log ID: 621d2b0f5a5370a82628edcc
Connecting to:      mongodb+srv://cluster0.8tjjn.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.2.2
MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
```

Any idea to solve this issue?? Thanks for your effort in advance.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 You may follow [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: Your first mistep was that you tried to install mongosh, which is SHELL, not the database service.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answer above -- On newer versions mac os x the root directory is read only so you will need place your mongo data directory somewhere else, see this thread:

[Read-only file system when attempting mkdir /data/db on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034955/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-data-db-on-mac)

I also needed to separately install the mongo command line tool from the cask:

```bash
$ brew install mongodb-community-shell
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for installing and managing applications on macOS. It is installed using the following command in the macOS terminal. Open up the terminal and paste the command:

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

The terminal runs through a series of installation operations, and will probably create folders in your local machine to accommodate Homebrews storage requirements. You can find more detailed instructions [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/developer-setup/). After it's installed, update the Homebrew dependencies and install MongoDB on the command line:

```sh
brew update
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

It will take a few seconds. Once it's done, create a directory so MongoDB can store its data.

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Now to make sure this data directory have the right permissions, you'll run this command:

```sh
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

Now our data directory is ready with the right permissions. Next run mongo daemon. Which is a service which runs in the background and listens for connections on a given port. Run this command:

```sh
mongod
```

Now mongo daemon will be running in the background and can be used by your applications. Next, check your MongoDB version:

```sh
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
```

The command-line results will show the version you have installed on your local machine. I recommend using the latest version of libraries and software whenever possible to avoid compatibility issues with client-side applications.

Comment: Can I suggest that you actually point out to OP that they installed Mongo Shell (a client application) not the Mongo database server?

Comment: Yeah, you are right!