# mongod command creating error when entered into command line

Tags: database, mongodb, backend

[Command line error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs2aO.png)

This is the error I get from trying to run `mongod` command, there are similar errors on the forum and none of the solution have worked.

Please help

Comment: Please have a look at this old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948789/mongod-complains-that-there-is-no-data-db-folder
Also the /data/db directory will need rwx permission for the user running mongod process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data directory path data/db

do these directories not exist?

the error code is complaining about them - so check it out...

Comment: The new catalina IOS update deleted my directories so I had to create a new one @Cahaba Data